# Slider switch in Flutter

Tags: flutter, switch-statement

I want to make a sliding switch like this

[image]

and I also made it through `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl()` but it is not meeting my requirements. I would like a similar slider switch.

I've made like this.

[image]

```
Neumorphic(
              style: NeumorphicStyle(
                  depth: NeumorphicTheme.embossDepth(context),
                  boxShape: const NeumorphicBoxShape.stadium(),
                  intensity: 1),
              child: ToggleSwitch(
                minWidth: 120.0,
                minHeight: 70,
                cornerRadius: 50.0,
                activeBgColors: const [
                  [Colors.cyan],
                  [Colors.cyan]
                ],
                inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey[200],
                inactiveFgColor: Colors.grey,
                totalSwitches: 2,
                labels: ['Agency', 'Freelancer'],
                radiusStyle: true,
                onToggle: (index) {},
              ),
            
            ),
```

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: now check it kindly.

Comment: If I slide my finger on it while selection then this slider should also slide as in iPhone.

Comment: Are you facing  declaration issue?

Comment: I've designed Like this but the problem I'm facing it is not sliding like in `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl()` a switch move with finger. If you test or watch video on it you can easily understand.
Also I've updated my code

Comment: if You can make it customize I'll be very thankful to you . Thanks

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I'm waiting for your kind reply

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package toggle_switch: ^1.4.0 and create it like this

```
SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      child: ToggleSwitch(
        minWidth: 90.0,
        cornerRadius: 20.0,
        activeBgColors: [const [Colors.cyan],const [Colors.cyan]],
        activeFgColor: Colors.white,
        inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
        inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
        initialLabelIndex: 1,
        totalSwitches: 2,
        labels: ['Agency', 'Freelancer'],
        radiusStyle: true,
        onToggle: (index) {
          print('switched to: $index');
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: But it is not sliding like in `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl()`

Comment: Kindly respond on it. How can I slide it.